# How To Implement Image Download With Authentication In AFNetworking 2.0?

Tags: ios8, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, xcode6, afnetworking-2

I have the following image download function that worked in AFNetworking 1.0.  It was part of my implementation of HTTPClient for AFNetworking 1.0.

```
- (void)downloadImageWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *downloadedImage))completionBlock identifier:(NSString *)identifier {
NSString* urlString = identifier;

AFImageRequestOperation* operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
                                      {
                                          //LogInfo(@"SUCCESS GETTING PHOTO: %@", response);
                                          completionBlock(image);
                                      }
                                                                                       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                                                           LogInfo(@"ERROR GETTING PHOTO IN downloadImageWithCompletionBlock.");

                                                                                       }];
[operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.strSPUser password:self.strSPPW persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}];
[self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

I'm not finding an easy transition/upgrade to AFNetworking 2.0 for the HTTPClient custom code that I wrote for AFNetworking 1.0.  As you can see in the function I am passing a credential to my restful webservice to download the image.

How can I implement the above image download function in AFNetworking 2.0?

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty much the same thing in AFNetworking 2. `AFHTTPRequestOperation` has both a `credential` property and a `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock:` method.

Comment: You really need me to copy-paste your code sample and replace `setAuthenticationChallengeBlock` with `setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock`? It's the same code.